# How can one extract every payload from warc.wet.gz?

Tags: python, common-crawl, warc

I have been trying to extract the text data from Common Crawl's wet files. I am currently using warc parser by Internet Archieve https://github.com/internetarchive/warc

```
import warc
w = warc.open(fileName)
for record in w:
  text = record.payload.read()
```

But this method gives less than half data that is there in payload.
Is there any other better method which can give all the data that is there in each of the payload in a file.

Comment: Can you give an example on what less than half data means?

Comment: Suppose there are in total 100K records, this method will only give us about 45K records

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36173786/python-cannot-read-warc-gz-file-completely Check this out. I'm guessing you are facing the same problem as mentioned here too - https://github.com/internetarchive/warc/issues/21

Comment: hey, was this solved?

Comment: Nope, I never got around it. Instead I cleaned the raw file reading line by line.

Answer (score 0):

The warc library has a bug with its gzip handling which causes warc fail to read the entire WET file. To overcome the bug, you should use Python's gzip library to decompress the file stream on the fly as below:

```
import gzip
import warc
gzip_fobj = gzip.open(wet_file, "r")
warc_fobj = warc.WARCFile(fileobj=gzip_fobj, compress=False)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import requests
from warcio.archiveiterator import ArchiveIterator
from requests_file import FileAdapter
def print_f_records(fpath,f_out,num):
    record_count = 0
    conversion_count = 0
    header_count = 0
    splitter = "://"
    mx = num
    s = requests.session()
    s.mount('file://',FileAdapter())
    resp = s.get(fpath, stream=True)
    for record in ArchiveIterator(resp.raw, arc2warc=True):
        record_count +=1
        if record.rec_type == 'warcinfo':
            print(record.raw_stream.read())
        elif record.rec_type == 'conversion':
            conversion_count +=1
            if record.raw_stream.read is not None:
                if record.rec_headers.get_header('Content-Type') == 'text/plain':
                    header_count +=1
                    if header_count > mx:
                        continue
                    print("\n text/plain header no: ", header_count)
                    prefix = f"a{header_count}_"        # filenames will begin with a<header_count>
                    fname1 = (record.rec_headers.get_header('WARC-Target-URI'))
                    fname = fname1.split(splitter)[1]   # get the name part which follows ://
                    fname = prefix + fname[:22] + '.txt'    # keep entire file name to 32 characters or less
                    fname = fname.replace("/", "_")
                    content = record.content_stream().read()
                    f = open(fname, 'wb')               # note the wb; write in binay mode because the content is characters
                    f.write(content)
                    f.close
                    line = f'{fname1},{fname}' + "\n" # keep a record of the url translations
                    f_out.write(line)
                    print("created text file: ", fname)
                    if header_count == mx:
                        print(f"\n... completed {mx} txt files ... \n")
    print("Number of records: ", record_count)
    print("Number of conversion types: ", conversion_count)
    print("Number of text/plain http_headers: ", header_count)
    print("\nFINISHED")
warc_wet_gz ='file:////home/psl/CCrawl/text_extraction/text_from_wet/CC-MAIN-20230928063033-20230928093033-00593.warc.wet.gz'
print(f'\n warc.wet.gz file is {warc_wet_gz}')
num=100
f_out=open("wet_list_out.txt", 'w')
print_f_records(warc_wet_gz, f_out, num)
f_out.close()
```

Comment: The above code extracts the first 100 text "payloads" from the .warc.wet.gz file.
The 100 created text files have shortened names which correspond to their associated url in the warc.wet.gz file. Many of the urls are too long to be used as as convenient names. The file wet_list_out.txt is generated and provides the correspondence between the shortened .txt file names and the associated urls.

Comment: The above code works. Of course you need to replace warc_wet_gz with the full path name of your own .warc.wet.gz file. If you want all the payloads, not just the first 100, set num to a very large number. Variable num was tacilty assumed to be 100 in the initial post. Why was it rated as not useful? The problem is solved. If you find issues with it please make specific suggestions.